# Transformation tools gizmos not working

Tags: objects, transforms

I have a problem with a project im working on; when I try to use any of the transformation gizmos they just dissappear when i click on them and the subtool I have in the selection tool is the one that actually activates. Ill attach a video to make it more clear.
When i start a new project the gizmos work fine. Ill appreciate any help you guys can provide with this matter

Im working in Blender 3.4 for windows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf8oI.jpg

[image]

Comment: my first guess was that it had something to do with the local view, but i couldn't reproduce the problem with it.
Still, it would be worth a try:
Why is everything on local view here?
Does something change when you switch to default or global?
My second idea was if it could have something to do with the fact that you pressed `numpad + /`, which hides all other objects, but even that in combination with local view doesn't have the shown effect on me.

As always:
Without blend file difficult to answer...
Show us the file, then we know more

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: right click vs. left click select issue?